# Can a test user 'LIKE' a brand page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, integration-testing

I'm building an tab for a brand page, which I am testing via Cucumber/Selenium.   I have created several test users in different states, but am hanging up on creating a test user who LIKEs my brand.

When I visit my own brand page logged in as my real facebook user, I see a LIKE button.

When I visit my brand page logged in as a test user, I do not see an option to LIKE the page.

I have had no trouble creating or testing users who have given my tab/app permissions.  All test users are associated with the brand page in the developers app.

Is it possible to have a test user like an existing brand page, or are there other suggestions for how to test this user scenario?

Thanks

Comment: I've accidentally voted to close this while trying to move this to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/, I'll flag a mod to sort my mistake.

Comment: you were't trying to game the system and get free likes were you?

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation, test users cannot like public pages.

> Test users cannot fan a public Page or create public content on them like writing on a Page's wall. A Test user can however view and interact with the app tab on the Page if they are associated with that app.

If you log in as a test user, then create a page as that user, then you can "like" it, and you may be able to do this test.