# How can a Facebook test user populate it's likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I am building an app that relies on the `user_likes` permission and checks what artists (music) has a particular user liked. I thought of using test users to automate my app's testing, but it seems I cannot like things as that user. If this is the case, test users are pretty useless for me.

Is there a way to like an artist (say, Avicii) with my test user?

Answer (score 5):

Test Users cannot like the pages that are already existing in Facebook. To test your functionality, you will have to create new pages and test.

Comment: I need to have real data, such as artists, liked by my test users. Fake data won't help because I connect to other services to fetch data about those artists.

Comment: As a Test User, you cannot like real pages and send friend request to real users. What I would suggest is you can mimic the real pages by creating test pages and test your app. All information regarding Test Users are given here [Facebook Test User documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users). Additionally you can view this question which is similar to yours [Similar stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509643/can-a-test-user-like-a-brand-page)

Comment: As I said, I cannot create fake, test pages for artists because all related 3rd-party services I use need the "official" ID of the artist's page. So I really need to interact with the real pages. It would be great if this access could be sandboxed somehow.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes Facebook doesn't give any sandbox access to test our apps. I would like you to join this group (Facebook Developer Community). Just search it in Facebook, you'll find it. Once you're accepted in the group, ask your question there. Someone will help you.